# Why does Marionette's Region.show() not work after a call to Region.close()?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have the following situation. When I am replacing a region with another one by calling `someRegion.show()`, everything works fine. But when a close the region first by calling `close()` and then `show()` a new one - it is not show.

It is strange to me, because in the Marionette docs it is explained, that `someRegion.close()` method is called every time a region is replaced with a new one by calling `someRegion.show()`
What is the reason for that?

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Are you receiving any console error?

Answer (score -1):

Based on Marionette documentation there is nothing wrong if you `close` a region and then you call `show` with a new one.

As you can read in the [Annotated Source Code](http://marionettejs.com/annotated-src/backbone.marionette) the `close` method performs the following check.

```
var view = this.currentView;
if (!view || view.isClosed){ return; }
```

Here a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsWdN/) example (close footer first and then open it).